# How can I filter by date to get this week vs previous week Counts from a QuerySet?

Tags: python, django, aggregate-functions

I have the following two annotated QuerySets which I have generated separately by extracting `this_wk` and `prev_wk` from a data set, then performing the annotation. I would like to merge them together before returning them.

```
data = {
    'this_wk': QuerySet([{'this_total': 3, 'dept': 2}, 
                         {'this_total': 2, 'dept': 1}, 
                         {'this_total': 1, 'dept': 3}]),
    'prev_wk': QuerySet([{'prev_total': 2, 'dept': 3}])}
```

Expected:

```
QuerySet([{'this_total': 3, 'prev_total': None, 'dept': 2},
          {'this_total': 2, 'prev_total': None, 'dept': 1}, 
          {'this_total': 1, 'prev_total': 2, 'dept': 3}]),
```

Alternatively, is there a way of aggregating this directly so that I go straight from a set of items with date fields? Here's how I am currently generating the two QuerySets:

```
previous_items = Widget.objects.filter(start__gte=prev_start).filter(start__lte=prev_end)
prev_ranking = previous_items.values('dept').annotate(prev_total=Count('dept'))

this_items = Widget.objects.filter(start__gte=this_start
    ).filter(start__lte=this_end)
this_ranking = this_items.values('dept'
    ).annotate(this_total=Count('dept')
    ).order_by('-this_total')
```

Is there a way to chain these two annotations together so that I end up with a single QuerySet grouped and ranked for each `Dept` depending on how many `Widgets` it was used by this week, but also with an added field that says how many `Widgets` it was used by the previous week?

I'm thinking something like this:

```
items = Widget.objects.filter(start__gte=prev_start
    ).filter(start__lte=this_end
    ).annotate(prev_total=Count('dept')  # can I restrict this to the previous week?
    ).annotate(this_total=Count('dept')  # can I restrict this to the current week?
    ).order_by('-this_total')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are thinking seems correct for your case. In order to achieve what you need you can apply the following:

1. Small but helpful is the [`range`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#range) lookup, which lets you filter between two values
2. To restrict your `annotate` arguments, you need to use [conditional aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-aggregation).

In the end your query will look like this:

```
items = Widget.objects.filter(start__range=(prev_start, this_end))
                      .values('dept')
                      .annotate(
                           prev_total=Count(
                               Case(
                                   When(start__lte=prev_end, then=1)),                 
                                   output_field=IntegerField())),
                           this_total=Count(
                               Case(
                                   When(start__gte=this_start, then=1), 
                                   output_field=IntegerField())))
                       .order_by('-this_total')
```

---

**EDIT DUE TO COMMENT:**

*This step is not needed in this case, this would help to build an annotation to sum the values of the filtered `dept` fields.*

3. I would utilize [`F()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45593440/how-to-execute-arithmetic-operations-between-model-fields-in-django) expression to take the value of each `dept` field inside the annotation, and [`Sum`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#sum) function instead of `Count` to add those values together.

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely along the right lines. It's just missing `.values('dept')` before the first `annotate` to get exactly what I'm looking for.
Also, why use the `F` expression and `Sum` rather than `Count`? Because of the race condition mentioned in the linked docs?

Comment: @JamieBull I was under the assumption that you needed to add the `dept` values together and have their sum. If this is not the case and you need just to count how many `dept` values there are, then I will edit the answer :). In the mean time, I will edit the `values('dept')` in the answer!

Comment: Yes, it's just counting how many department values there are, so then I don't need the `F`?

Comment: @JamieBull In that case you do not need `F()`. I will edit my answer to match your case.

Comment: @JamieBull I gave the answer 1 hour before John. Is there anything wrong with it? I am just curious if you got the correct results with it.

Comment: All I saw was the "check out conditional aggregation" part and the link, so went off to read about it. By the time I came back there were two answers, one of which was much better explained and referenced the current docs. I only now realise that what we eventually arrived at is the same as your original answer, but with the addition of explanations which I think make it the better answer for anyone who arrives here in future.

Answer (score 2):

check out conditional aggregation:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-aggregation

```
items = (Widget.objects.filter(start__range=(prev_start, this_end))
         .values('dept')
         .annotate(prev_total=Count(Case(When(start__lte=prev_end, then='dept'), output_field=IntegerField())),
                   this_total=Count(Case(When(start__gte=this_start, then='dept'), output_field=IntegerField()))
                   )
         .order_by('-this_total'))
```